# Prove $P(X=k \mid X+Y=n) = \frac1{n+1}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $f_X(k) = f_Y(k)= p(1-p)^k~$ for all $k = 0,1,2,\ldots$
for some $0 < p < 1$. Show that for any $n \ge 0$
$$P(X=k \mid X+Y=n) = \frac1{n+1}$$ 
for any $0 \le k \le n$.

---

What is confusing me is that this is not a true geometric as the range of $k$ starts at $0$.

This is what I have so far but any help in the correct direction would be great because I am lost.

Consider 
$$P(X=k \mid X+Y=n)= {P(X=k , X+Y=n) \over P(X+Y=n)} 
={P(X=k)\cdot P(Y=n-k)\over P(X+Y=n)}.$$
Also $P(X=k) = p(1-p)^k~$ for all $k \ge 0$,
and $P(Y=n-k) = p(1-p)^{n-k}~$ for all $n-k > 0$,
so $P(X=k)\cdot P(Y=n-k) = p^2(1-p)^n$.

Comment: Correction, X and Y are independent, discrete random variables. sorry about that.

Comment: So far, so good. Now, $\displaystyle P(X+Y=n) = \sum_{i=0}^n P(X=i, Y=n-i)$.

Comment: Maybe as a guidance, the heuristic is: $X,Y$ can be viewed as "number of tails before first head" for a biased coin. We are looking for "number of tails before first head, given that there are $n$ tails before second head" or "given that exactly one out of $n+1$ flips is head, at which position does it occur?" - The latter variant is clearly symmetric in the $n+1$ positions, hence uniform.

Answer (score 1):

From where you stopped you can do the following:

$$\mathbb{P}(X+Y=n)=\sum_{i=0}^n \mathbb{P}(X=i,Y=n-i) \overset{independence}{=} \sum_{i=0}^n \mathbb{P}(X=i)\mathbb{P}(Y=n-i).$$
Now using the densities we get
$$ \sum_{i=0}^n \mathbb{P}(X=i)\mathbb{P}(Y=n-i) = \sum_{i=0}^n p(1-p)^i \cdot p (1-p)^{n-i} = \sum_{i=0}^n p^2(1-p)^n = (n+1)p^2(1-p)^n.$$

Finally using the quotiënt you have in your approach we have that
$$ \mathbb{P}(X=k \mid X+Y=n)=\frac{p^2(1-p)^n}{(n+1)p^2(1-p)^n}=\frac{1}{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

> What is confusing me is that this is not a true geometric as the range of $k$ starts at $0$.

There are **two** distributions commonly named Geometric.   Which one is used depends on the text; I recommend specifying the support to avoid ambiguity.

The probability distribution of the count of failures *before* the first success, in a series of iid Bernoulli trials, is : $X\sim\mathcal{Geo}_0(p)$ $$~\mathsf P(X{=}x)~=~(1-p)^xp~\big[{x\in\{0,1,...\}}\big]$$

The probability distribution of the count of trials *until* the first success is : $Z\sim\mathcal{Geo}_1(p)$ $$\mathsf P(Z{=}z) ~=~ (1-p)^{z-1}p~\big[{z\in\{1,2,...\}}\big]$$

This is sometimes called the *shifted geometric distribution*.

Here we are using the former: distribution of failures *before* the first success .

---

As per your approach we have: $\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid X{+}Y{=}n) =\dfrac{\mathsf P(X{=}x)~\mathsf P(Y{=}n{-}x)}{\mathsf P(X{+}Y{=}n)}$

What is $X+Y$?   It is the count of failures before the *second* success.   So the probability of 1 success and $n$ failures in some arrangement, then a second success is: $$\mathsf P(X{+}Y{=}n) = \binom{n+1}{1}(1-p)^{n}p^2~\big[{n\in\{0,1,...\}}\big]$$

The rest should fall into place.